# android apk don't see time, battery,wireless

Tags: android, apk

On Android phones, there are icons at the top such as time, battery percentage, network power, wireless connection, etc. I prepared an apk, but when I open it, the icons at the top do not appear. How do I make these visible? thank you in advance

I couldn't find what to do.

Comment: Sounds to me like you have activated full screen mod in your app. As you did not provide details on how you "prepare an APK" the chance ho get an answer is pretty low. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask